# Partial Derivatives Tend to Zero implies Limit to Infinity Exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ exist and are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose that $$|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,y)|+|\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x,y)|\leq\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}g(x,y)$ exists.

---

I am not very sure how to go about proving this. I know that the first condition (partial derivatives exist and continuous) implies that $g$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Then, I am thinking of using Taylor's Theorem somehow. One problem I face is I don't know what is the candidate limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}g(x,y)$ which makes it hard to prove it using the Epsilon-Delta method.

Another line of thinking could be the fundamental theorem of line integrals (as suggested by a commenter below). Again, I face problems coming up with the full proof.

Thanks for any help!

Updates (I am working on this question in the meantime):

If we are proving using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition, we need to show that there exists $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $R>0$ such that whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>R$ we have $|g(x,y)-c|<\epsilon$. Finding a candidate for $c$ seems very hard to me, perhaps the way is to prove by contradiction.

I am following AlexM.'s solution, which looks promising, except for some details in the inequality. I am thinking if that can be fixed using application of Mean Value Theorem for Definite Integrals.

Comment: Use $g(x,y)=g(x_{0},y_{0})+\int_{0}^d(\partial_{x}g\gamma'_{1}+\partial_{y}g\gamma'_{2})ds$ for an curve from $(x_{0},y_{0})$ to $(x,y)$ parametrized for instance by arc length. Then use $\epsilon, \delta$...

Comment: @Lucien May I ask what theorem is this? Thanks.

Comment: Just the fundamental theorem of calculs, multivariate version...

Comment: @Lucien What is $(x_0,y_0)$? An arbitrary point?

Comment: It might help to consider that the absolute value of the derivative along any curve $c(s)$ parametrised by its length is going to be $\leq 1/(x^2 + y^2)$. This converges absolutely as $(x^2 + y^2) \rightarrow \infty$, so the limit along any line extending from the origin out to infinity is going to exist. Furthermore, take a disk with growing radius and integrate around said disk to find that the difference in this limit, as you vary the direction of the line, shrinks. There is hence just one limit for $\infty$ in any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Showing that the limit is the same in all $\infty$ `directions':

Let $R \in \mathbb R_+$. We will take the limit of $R \rightarrow \infty$ and see that a circle of this radius around the origin contains an ever-shrinking range of values. This shows that the limit is the same in all directions.

For any curve $c(s)$ parametrised by its length, we know that
$$\begin{align}
\left| \frac{d g(c(s))}{ds} \right| &= \left| \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{d c_x(s)}{ds} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \frac{d c_y(s)}{ds} \right|\\
& \leq \left| \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \right| + \left| \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right| \tag{Parametrising by length}\\
& \leq \frac 1 {x^2 + y^2} \tag{Evaluated at $(x(s), y(s)) = (c_x(s), c_y(s))$}
\end{align}$$
By choosing a circle, we've made the job easy: $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$. Between any two points on a circle, the largest distance between them allows for the largest possible discrepancy in value, and this length is $\pi R$. An upper bound on the discrepancy in the value between points is 
$$|g(p_1) - g(p_2) | \leq \int_{p_1}^{p_2} \left| \frac{d g(c(s))}{ds} \right| ds \leq \int_{p_1}^{p_2} \frac 1 {R^2} ds \; \leq \frac{\pi R}{R^2} = \frac \pi R$$
Now of course, as $R\rightarrow \infty$, we can clearly see that this tends to zero. So the difference between the limits at infinity (if they exist) tends to zero, and so there is either one limit for any $\infty$ direction, or none at all.

### Showing that there is *a* limit in an $\infty$ direction:

We can choose any path we like to find that there is a limit. For convenience, let's choose the path along the $x$ axis: $c(s) = (s, 0)$. Naively, we could use the same technique as before to say that the value as $s \rightarrow \infty$ is
$$\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} g(0,s) = g(0,0) + \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,x') d x'$$
which converges *iff* the integral converges. Does the integral converge? Well, we know something about its *absolute convergence*:
$$\int_{0}^\infty \left| \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,x') \right| d x' \leq \int_{0}^\infty \left| \frac 1 {x'^2} \right| d x'$$
but this upper bounding integral doesn't converge! No matter. We can make it converge by starting a little to the right of the origin. Let's say $x=1$, though it really doesn't matter where. Then:
$$\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} g(0,s) = g(0,1) + \int_{1}^\infty \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,x') d x'$$
and we know that the integral *converges absolutely* because
$$\int_{1}^\infty \left| \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,x') \right| d x' \leq \int_{1}^\infty \left| \frac 1 {x'^2} \right| d x' = 1$$
Absolute convergence implies convergence, and hence the limit exists.

Comment: I frankly don't see how this differs from @HenningMakholm's solution given in another answer - except for containing more details.

Comment: @Alex M. - I agree. The asker did not seem particularly satisfied with that answer however, so I thought I'd give my own explanation in case it helped. I independently came to the same approach which is not really surprising.

Comment: Thanks. I like your proof. Just to check, is it conceptually wrong to bound $|g(p_1) - g(p_2) |\leq \frac{2\pi R}{R^2}$ instead of $\frac{\pi R}{R^2}$? I see this as the maximum "arc-length" between $p_1$ and $p_2$ in the integral $\int_{p_1}^{p_2} \frac 1 {R^2} ds$.

Comment: @yoyostein - That would be OK to do, yes. That's also an upper bound. The reason I used $\pi R$ instead of $2 \pi R$ is that if the distance between two points is more than $\pi R$, then we are going the *long way* around the circle. We can go the other direction around the circle instead which is shorter. So the maximum distance is actually $\pi R$.

Answer (score 4):

Line integrals seem like the way to go. Consider a circle of radius $R$ around the origin. Since
$$ \sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\Bigr)^2+\Bigl(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\Bigr)^2} \le \frac{1}{R^2} $$
on the circle, by integrating along the circle we find that the maximal possible difference between two points that both have norm $R$ is $\pi/R$ which goes to $0$ as $R\to\infty$.

Furthermore
$$ g(x,0) = g(1,0) + \int_1^x \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,0)\, dt $$
tends to a limit for $x\to \infty$, because the improper integral
$$ \int_1^\infty \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,0)\, dt $$
exists, by squeezing between $\int_1^\infty \frac{\pm 1}{t^2} \,dt $

These two facts combine to show that the value of $g$ on all rays away from the origin converge *uniformly* towards $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x,0)$.

Comment: Thanks. I thought $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^2}\,dt$ does not converge? How does the squeeze theorem work here?

Comment: @yoyostein: Valid point; I've updated the lower limit such that we do get convergence.

Comment: How about two pints that do not have the same norm?

Comment: @Gordon: Sorry, I don't understand that question.

Comment: You have shown that the maximal possible difference between two points that both have norm $R$ is $\pi/R$. How about two points that do not have the same norm $R$?

Comment: @Gordon: Ah, you mean pOints, not pints. Sorry, somehow missed that. Each of the points, if they are far enough from the origin, can _separately_ not have a value that differs by too much from $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x,0)$. For any $\varepsilon$ you like, split it between an allowance for going around a circle to the $x$-axis and an allowance for going right along the $x$-axis to infinity.

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm. If you can make it rigorous, it would be more helpful.

Comment: @Gordon: I prefer to leave something for the OP to do.

Answer (score 1):

We first show that the function is bounded. For any point $(x, y)$ such that $x^2+y^2 >1$, let $n$ be the largest integer such that $\frac{1}{2^n}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le 1$, and $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} > 1$. Note that 
\begin{align*}
&\ f(x, y) - f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}, \frac{y}{2^n}\right) \\
=&\ \int_0^1 \frac{df}{d t}\left(tx+(1-t)\frac{x}{2^n}, \, ty+(1-t)\frac{y}{2^n}\right)dt\\
=&\ \int_0^1 \left(\Big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\Big)x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \Big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\Big)y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) f\left(tx+(1-t)\frac{x}{2^n}, \, ty+(1-t)\frac{y}{2^n}\right)dt.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\left|f(x, y) - f\left(\frac{x}{2^n}, \frac{y}{2^n}\right)\right| &\le\int_0^1\frac{\big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\big)(|x|+|y|)}{\big(tx+(1-t)\frac{x}{2^n}\big)^2 + \big(ty+(1-t)\frac{y}{2^n}\big)^2 }dt\\
&\le\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\int_0^1 \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}{\Big(\frac{1}{2^n}+\big(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\big)t\Big)^2}dt\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} (2^n-1)\\
&\le 2\sqrt{2}\frac{2^{n-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
&\le 2\sqrt{2}.
\end{align*}
That is, the function $f$ is bounded. Then, there exists a sequence $\{(x_n, y_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{x_n^2+y_n^2}=\infty,
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n, y_n) = \alpha,
\end{align*}
where $|\alpha| < \infty$.

Next, we show that, for any two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ sufficiently far from the origin, $f(x_1, y_1) - f(x_2, y_2)$ is sufficiently small. If the two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ has the same norm $R$, then, from the answer by @HenningMakholm, there exist $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ such that $0 \le \theta_1 < \theta_2 \le 2\pi$, and 
\begin{align*}
f(x_1, y_1) - f(x_2, y_2) &= \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{d}{d\theta}f(R\cos\theta, R \sin\theta) d\theta\\
&= \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\left(-R\sin\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial x} +R\cos\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \right)f(R\cos\theta, R \sin\theta) d\theta.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|f(x_1, y_1) - f(x_2, y_2)| &\le \frac{2\pi}{R}.
\end{align*}
For two points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ that do not have the same norm, for example, 
\begin{align*}
R_1 = \sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2} < \sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}=R_2,
\end{align*}
then the two points $(x_2, y_2)$ and $\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1}x_1, \frac{R_2}{R_1}y_1\right)$ have the same norm $R_2$. Moreover,
\begin{align*}
&\ f\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1}x_1, \frac{R_2}{R_1}y_1\right) - f(x_1, y_1) \\
=&\ \int_0^1\frac{df}{d t}\left(t\frac{R_2}{R_1}x_1+(1-t)x_1, \, t\frac{R_2}{R_1}y_1+(1-t)y_1\right)dt\\
=&\ \int_0^1 \left(\Big(\frac{R_2}{R_1}-1\Big)x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \Big(\frac{R_2}{R_1}-1\Big)y_1\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) f\left(t\frac{R_2}{R_1}x_1+(1-t)x_1, \, t\frac{R_2}{R_1}y_1+(1-t)y_1\right)dt.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\left|f\left(\frac{R_2}{R_1}x_1, \frac{R_2}{R_1}y_1\right) - f(x_1, y_1)\right| &\le \int_0^1\frac{\Big(\frac{R_2}{R_1}-1\Big)(|x_1|+|y_1|)}{\big(t\frac{R_2}{R_1}x_1+(1-t)x_1\big)^2 +\big(t\frac{R_2}{R_1}y_1+(1-t)y_1\big)^2}dt\\
&\le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}}\int_0^1\frac{\frac{R_2}{R_1}-1}{\left(1+\Big(\frac{R_2}{R_1}-1\Big)t \right)^2}dt\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}}\Big(1-\frac{R_1}{R_2}\Big)\\
&\le \frac{\sqrt{2}}{R_1}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
|f(x_1, y_1) - f(x_2, y_2)| &\le \frac{2\pi}{R_2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{R_1}.
\end{align*}